# Show widget outside sidebar

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a theme total made by me. I need to show [Sidebar Login plugin](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-login/)'s widget in header. I tried

```
<div class="login"><?php the_widget('sidebar-login');?></div>
```

Page load without error and I have a space occupied by that div, but there is nothing inside. Maybe it is because I insert no `$instance` and no `$args` after `$widget`, but I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by:

Display Widget outside Sidebar

```
<?php the_widget( 'Contact_Widgets' ); ?>
```

For more info visit: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-widget-outside-sidebar/

Comment: @Michele please visit this link this will work for you. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-widget-outside-sidebar/

Comment: I solved using <?php the_widget('Sidebar_Login_Widget');?>  . Still thanks friend :)